# Compute $(df)_a$ in chart $\varphi_1:U=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x\neq0\}\rightarrow\varphi_1(U)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, inverse

> Suppose that for a submanifold $H$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we have two charts
>
> $$\varphi_1:U=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x\neq0\}\rightarrow\varphi_1(U)$$
>
> $$\varphi_2:U=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:y\neq0\}\rightarrow\varphi_2(U).$$
>
> s.t. $\varphi_1(x,y,z)=(y,z)$ and $\varphi_2(x,y,z)=(x,z)$.
>
> Let $f:H\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be the morphism $f(x,y,z)=(x,z)$.
>
> Compute $(df)_a$ in those charts.

My attempt (for $\varphi_1$):

I know that $$(df)_a=\sum_i \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}(\varphi(a))(dx_i)_a$$

where $f \circ \varphi^{-1} = \phi$.

My question is: what is the expression of $\varphi_1^{-1}$, in order to get $\phi$? Maybe it is a silly question but I'm not used to these problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definition of the charts isn't clear: I assume that the domains are actually $U_i \cap H$, but what are the expressions for $\varphi_i$? Are they just the identity restricted to $U_i$?

Comment: $\varphi:U \subseteq H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Those $U_i$ aren't open subsets of a general submanifold of $H$. On the other hand, charts on $\Bbb{R}^3$ induce charts on $H$ exactly because $H$ is a submanifold. Still, what are the expressions of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$? For example, what is $\varphi_1(x,y,z)$?

Comment: We don't require the $U_i$ open, but $\varphi_i(U_i)$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's a definition for coordinate chart. Let me edit the question with additional information that I clearly forgot

Comment: Since $\varphi_i$ are homeomorphisms, $\varphi_i(U_i)$ is open if and only if $U_i$ is open.

Comment: Oh you're right becaus eof the manifold topology... Let me tell you where this comes from: We have $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $H=F^{-1}(0)$ where $F$ is the defining equation of $H$. Since is a fiber and DF is surjective, $H$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$. By the same theorem, I build those charts (in fact there are three, but two are enough to compute) and they are the $\varphi_i$ that I presented above, so yes, your first comment is right.

Comment: By the way, $H=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2=1+z^2\}$

Comment: Then those aren't charts on $H$ because they aren't invertible. For example $\varphi_1^{-1}(s,t) = (\pm \sqrt{1 + t^2 - s^2}, s, t)$.

Comment: So we have 6 charts for H by this way? Instead of using $\neq$ we use > and <?

Comment: $H$ is a one-sheeted [hyperboloid](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%3D%3D%201%20%2B%20z%5E2) (incidentally, one of my favourite surfaces) and you can cover it with the four projections on the planes $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. The charts are $\{(U_x^{\pm}, \varphi_x^{\pm}), (U_y^{\pm},\varphi_y^{\pm})\}$ with $U_x^+ = \{(x,y,z) \in H : x > 0\}$, $\varphi_x^+ (x,y,z) = (y,z)$, and similarly for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cover the one-sheeted hyperboloid
$$
H = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 + z^2 \right\}
$$
with the four charts $(U_x^{\pm},\varphi_x^{\pm}),(U_y^{\pm},\varphi_y^{\pm})$ where
$$
\begin{align}
U_x^{\pm} &:= \left\{ (x,y,z) \in H : x \gtrless 0 \right\} &
\varphi_x^{\pm}(x,y,z) &= (y,z) \\
U_y^{\pm} &:= \left\{ (x,y,z) \in H : y \gtrless 0 \right\} &
\varphi_y^{\pm}(x,y,z) &= (x,z)
\end{align}
$$

Now, observe that your map $f(x,y,z) = (x,z)$ coincides with $\varphi_y^{\pm}$ on $U_y^{\pm}$, so it is clearly differentiable on $U_y^{\pm}$. Furthermore, we have
$$
(f \circ (\varphi_y^{\pm})^{-1}) (x,z) = (x,z)
$$
so $J_a(f) = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ for every $a \in U_y^{\pm}$.

The remaining points to check lie on a hyperbola
$$
H_0 := H \setminus (U_y^+ \cup U_y^-) = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in H : y = 0 \right\}
$$
Since $(\varphi_x^{\pm})^{-1} (y,z) = \left(\pm \sqrt{1 + z^2 - y^2},y,z\right)$ we have
$$
(f \circ (\varphi_x^{\pm})^{-1})(y,z) = \left(\pm \sqrt{1 + z^2 - y^2}, z\right)
$$
which is indeed differentiable in a small enough neighbourhood of $H_0$.

*Note: Since this seems to be homework I'll leave the computation of the Jacobian (or equivalently, of the differential) to you. Drop a comment below if you need help with it.*

Comment: Thanks for answering. This was not homework, I had an exam today about this and I made sure I understand this. I learned yesterday that those ''charts'' that I wrote are absurd, I was interpreting wrongly the proof of the theorem that I stated above.

Comment: I see. Sorry that I didn't have time to write it out earlier, then.

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing an answer, I have the habit of writing an answer myself when there is not one to remember later and it may be useful to somebody else. Fortunately the manifold of my exam was $M=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x+y=5, x+z=cos^2(y)\}$ and therefore we have a global chart and things get easy